# Retrieving an image using CloudKit and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cloudkit

I am new to CloudKit.

I would like to know how I can retrieve from the database only one image. I created a new record type and added a Asset type in it with the name EventsImage. Now I want to retrieve this image and place it in an ImageView I have on my View controller. This is an image of what the View looks like (it is not a tableViewController).

[image: 1]

(There is an ImageView in the middle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a snippet in which I recover an image from my database. I fetch CKRecord using the record ID.

```
self.publicDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: recordID, completionHandler: { (record: CKRecord?, error: Error?) -> (Void) in
    guard let record = record else
    {
        if let error = error
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async 
            {
                completionHandler(SeeYuuResult.error(message: error.localizedDescription))
            }
        }

        return
    }

    // Here is where the image is recovered
    if let asset = record["avatar"] as? CKAsset, let data = try? Data(contentsOf: asset.fileURL)
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async 
        {
        avatar_image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }   
})
```